# Lines are angular

Tags: java, image, paint, drag

I want to paint on an image what the user is painting on the screen. For that I created an image array where the images are saved. That all works how it should. But if I draw a circle or some other round shapes it is shown very angular and not nearly round. My code:

```
private void onPress(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                         
    images[actualLevel] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) images[actualLevel].getGraphics();
    g2d.fillOval(evt.getX() - 200, evt.getY() - 200, 400, 400);
    lastX = evt.getX();
    lastY = evt.getY();
    g2d = (Graphics2D) display.getGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(images[actualLevel], 0, 0, null);
    g2d = (Graphics2D) paPaintingArea.getGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(display, 0, 0, paPaintingArea);
    System.out.println(actualLevel);
}                        

private void onDrag(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                        
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) images[actualLevel].getGraphics();
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
    g2d.drawLine(lastX, lastY, evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    lastX = evt.getX();
    lastY = evt.getY();
    g2d = (Graphics2D) display.getGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(images[actualLevel], 0, 0, null);
    g2d=(Graphics2D)paPaintingArea.getGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(display, 0, 0,paPaintingArea);
}
```

display is the image that is painted on the panel after saving the image in the array.

Why are my lines so angular and how can I fix it?

Comment: General advice: you should think about providing examples of what you expect and what you get instead. Without them it's hard to understand what your actual problems is - we'd only be able to guess.

Comment: I expect: The user draws something on the screen and it is painted exactly like he painted it - also a round shape if he paints it
I get: A shape that isn't round even if the user painted something round

Comment: "it is shown very angular" - without a visual clue that's very prone to misunderstandings. Either you have a misconception or are doing something wrong but we can only guess what is the case.

Comment: Yeah, It's hard to understand what "very angular" means. can you add a screen capture maybe?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8r-TskcfbJEdTVsMjBHMmxxNWc/view?usp=sharing
here is a screen capture. I have drawn a circle with the mouse and that is what I see.